# Refining dataframe-based stacked bar plot in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis, stacked-chart

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart using PyCharm.
I am using matplotlib to explore at fullest its potentialities for simple data visualization.

My original code is for a group chart bar that displays cycle time for different teams. Such information come from a dataframe. The chart also includes autolabeling function (i.e. the height of each bar = continuous variable).

[image: Original Bar Chart - Group Distribution]

I am trying to convert such group bar chart in a stacked bar chart. The code below needs to be improved because of two factors:

- **labels for variables have too many decimals:** this issue did not occur for the grouped bar chart. The csv file and the derived data frame weren't altered. I am struggling to understand if and where to use *round* command. I guess the issue is either related to the autolabeling function, because datatype used is float (I need to see at least 1 decimal).
- **data labels are displaced:** as the auto labeling function was created for separated bars, the labels always matched the distance I wanted (based on the vertical offset). Unfortunately I did not figure out how to make sure that this distance is rather centered (see my example, the value for funnel time is at the height of squad time instead, and vice-versa). By logic, the issue should be that the height of each variable is defined ahead (*see rects3 in the code, value of bottom*) but I don't know how to reflect this in my auto-labeling variable.

[image: Messed up Stacked chart]

The question is what exactly in the code must be altered in order to have the values of cycle time centered?

The code (notes for you are marked in bold):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

'''PART 1 - Preprocess data -----------------------------------------------'''
#Directory or link of my CSV. This can be used also if you want to use API.
csv1 = r"C:\Users\AndreaPaviglianiti\Downloads\CT_Plot_DF.csv"

#Create and read dataframe. This is just to check the DF before plotting
df = pd.read_csv(csv1, sep=',', engine= 'python')
print(df, '\n')

#Extract columns as lists
squads = df['Squad_Name'].astype('str') #for our horizontal axis
funnel = df['Funnel_Time'].astype('float')
squadt = df['Squad_Time'].astype('float')
wait = df['Waiting_Time'].astype('float')
```

**Here I tried to set the rounding but without success**

```
'''PART 2 - Create the Bar Plot / Chart ----------------------------------'''
x = np.arange(len(squads))  #our labels on x will be the squads' names
width = 0.2  # the width of the bars. The bigger value, the larger bars
distance = 0.2
#Create objects that will be used as subplots (fig and ax).
#Each "rects" is the visualization of a yn value. first witdth is distance between X values,
    # the second is the real width of bars.


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x, funnel, width, color='red', label='Funnel Time')
rects2 = ax.bar(x, squadt, width, color='green', bottom=funnel, label='Squad Time')
rects3 = ax.bar(x, wait, width, bottom=funnel+squadt, color='purple', label='Waiting Time')


# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Mean Cycle Time (h)')
ax.set_xlabel('\n Squads')
ax.set_title("Squad's Cycle Time Comparison in Dec-2020 \n (in mean Hours)")
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(squads)
ax.legend()
fig.align_xlabels() #align labels to columns

# The function to display values above the bars
def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')
```

**Here I tried to change xytext="center" but I get error, I am supposed to use coordinates only or is there an alternative to change the position from the height to the center?**

```
#We will label only the most recent information. To label both add to the code "autolabel(rects1)"
    autolabel(rects1)
    autolabel(rects2)
    autolabel(rects3)
    fig.tight_layout()
    
    '''PART 3 - Execute -------------------------------------------------------'''
    plt.show()
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Pandas has `df.plot.bar(stacked=True)` which stacks the columns...

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answer my question. The purpose is to achieve the stacked chart while keeping the code as much similar as it is in order to compare differences in the end, for educational purposes. Also, this function takes into consideration the sum(Tot cycle time), which must be excluded instead.